# Are there any sources for high resolution (digital) manga?

Tags: resources

I've just got my first tablet and I'd love to explore manga with it. I've looked at a couple of Kindle samples from Amazon and also randomly sampled some fansub, and everything seems quite low res. The fansub I saw was ~0.75 megapixel. The Kindle version seems slightly sharper (not sure how to be more specific) but especially if zooming in on a panel it's noticeably blurry. It seems to me that modern screens with their insane pixel densities would be great canvasses for manga, and I just wondered if anyone's started going down that route.

Clarification: I don't have problems as such, the manga is legible. To draw an analogy, imagine I've bought a full HD TV but only have DVDs as a source. It would be nice to find an HD source for the HD display. And once you're used to 1080p, if you go back to DVDs they will seem less sharp (the blurriness I mentioned above). So are there any sources for high res manga, ie HD manga! (I realise I'm being vague by saying high-res - > 1MP would be a find, > 2MP would be great, but the higher the better for this question.)

Comment: maybe you're experiencing distortions from different scaling methods on your devices

Comment: Also you seem to be asking multiple questions within one post. Could you clarify by asking the same question in the post as in the title?

Comment: @user1306322 thanks for your comments. There's no distortion, it's simply not as sharp as it would've been with a higher res image. I'm not sure what other question you're seeing in the body?

Comment: @Andy There could be a lot of reasons for that, maybe the sources you are using are low-resolution, maybe your tablet screen has a problem or is just low-quality. I personally read manga on my tablet and have never had that kind of problem.

Comment: @KirKill Thanks, I think I'm using normal sources (Amazon, mangafox, mangahere). I've tried to clarify the Q - I don't have a problem, I'm just looking for even better!

Comment: What manga specifically have you looked at? Remember that not all manga was printed "in HD" ;-)

Comment: I've used Viz's app for the Amazon Kindle Fire and thought it looked pretty good. The downside for me was that's it's only Viz, so if you're not all about Shounen Jump and other Shueisha magazines, you might have trouble finding the content you want. The app itself is no prize either; it's a pain to navigate and downloads sometimes time out. Also, they limit the amount of zooming you can do, so they might be cheating somehow. But it did look a lot better than my other reader that accesses mangafox and mangahere.

Answer (score 2):

Hate to write a suggestion in an answer, but too new to comment.

Have you tried crunchyroll? If you pay for their premium membership you're supposed to get HD anime and manga (you can get a manga only subscription).

If you're looking at fan scanlations, some online reader sites downgrade the quality of uploaded chapters in order to make the pages load faster, which will result in jpg artifacting at times as well. If you're looking for higher quality, I suggest grabbing it from the scanlators' sites and/or using their readers if possible.

Comment: Please don't suggest illegal manga sites here. Thanks.

Comment: @nhahtdh apologies, I've edited the answer a bit

Comment: @Arty-chan for future reference, if you are unsure if a site is legal or not check [this page](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923),